# Creating nested arrays from a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have a database with some tables and columns.
I want to create a multidimensional array in PHP to store these values.

```
$tableData = array(array()); // I try to set up the multidimensional array.

/* 1: Get Table Names (works fine) */
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM myDatabase");
    $i=0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    {                   
        // Push the table name into the PHP array
        array_push($tableData, $row[0]);
    }


/* 2: Columns */
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($tableNames); $i++)
    {
        $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tableData[$i]");          
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            array_push($tableData[$i], $row); // ** ERROR THROWN: first argument must be an array ** //
        }
    }
```

How can I do this? I feel like this should be simple, but I've spent the last 4 hours banging my head on my keyboard and google trying to figure it out... plenty of tutorial on putting a multidimensional array into a SQL, but not much for the other way around!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to array(array()) to set up a multidimensional array. just push other array as a value.

try this:

```
foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) 
{
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tableName");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $tableData[$tableName] = $row;
    }
}
```

Comment: All answers seem correct but this one is the simplest. I am using a variation on this, using mysql_query("DESCRIBE $tableName") and $row['Field'] in place of "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tableName" and $row.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tableData = array(array());
...
   array_push($tableData, $row[0]);
...
```

This just means you end up with an array that looks like this:

```
array(array(), 'foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

You can't "set up a multi-dimensional array" like that. It should look more like this:

```
$tableData = array();
...
   array_push($tableData, array($row[0]));
...
```

With this, you'd end up with an array like:

```
array(array('foo'), array('bar'), array('baz'))
```

I guess you want more something along the lines of this though:

```
array('foo' => array('col1', 'col2', ...), 'bar' => array('col1', ...))
```

So you need to do something like this for the columns:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {  // much more useful than for()
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $tableName");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result[$tableName][] = $row;
    }
}
```

Good luck in experimenting more with this...
[`var_dump`](http://www.php.net/var_dump) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Your query for column names isn't correct. You should do something like `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable FROM mydb;` or `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable;`

SOURCE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

You probably want to do something like:

```
$tableData = array();

$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM myDatabase");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
{
    $tableData[$row[0]] = array();
}

foreach ($tableData as $table => $array)
{
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table FROM myDatabase");          
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $tableData[$table][] = $row[0];
    }
}
```

Although I haven't had a chance to run this code for errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tableData = array();

/* 1: Get Table Names (works fine) */
    $result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM myDatabase");
    $i=0;
    $tablenames = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) 
    {                   
        // Push the table name into the PHP array
        array_push($tablenames, $row[0]);
    }


/* 2: Columns */
    foreach($tablenames as $table)
    {
        $tableData[$table] = array();
        $result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            array_push($tableData[$table], $row);
        }
    }
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off addressing the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` directly and creating arrays based on that:

```
// table_schema is the database name. So you're looking up all of the tables
// and their respective columns.
$q = mysql_query( 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM COLUMNS WHERE '.
                  "TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase'" );

$output = array();
while( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q ) )
{
    // does an index exist for this table?
    if( !isset( $output[ $r[ 'table_name' ] ] ) )
         // no? create one
         $output[ $r[ 'table_name' ] ] = array();
    // append the array which exists at this index with the column name.
    $output[ $r[ 'table_name' ] ][] = $r[ 'column_name' ];
}
```